# TensorFlow multiple values for loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I'm working through this [RNN tutorial](https://r2rt.com/recurrent-neural-networks-in-tensorflow-i.html) to get a general idea of how to write an RNN using the lower level TensorFlow API. While I've gotten everything to work, I am getting different values for my total_loss depending on how I evaluate it within the session.

What is the difference in how the below losses are calculated? Why does running the train step with other nodes (i.e. in the same run statement) in the graph result in different loss values then when running the train step and other nodes separately (i.e. in different run statements)?

Here is the graph:

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch_size, num_steps], name = 'X')
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch_size, num_steps], name = 'Y')
initial_state = tf.zeros([batch_size, state_size])

X_one_hot = tf.one_hot(X, num_classes)
rnn_inputs = tf.unstack(X_one_hot, axis = 1)

Y_one_hot = tf.one_hot(Y, num_classes)
Y_one_hot_list = tf.unstack(Y_one_hot, axis = 1)

with tf.variable_scope('RNN_cell'):
    W = tf.get_variable('W', [num_classes + state_size, state_size])
    b = tf.get_variable('b', [state_size], initializer = tf.constant_initializer(0.0))

tf.summary.histogram('RNN_cell/weights', W)

# define the RNN cell
def RNNCell(rnn_input, state, activation = tf.tanh):
    with tf.variable_scope('RNN_cell', reuse = True):
        W = tf.get_variable('W', [num_classes + state_size, state_size])
        b = tf.get_variable('b', [state_size], initializer = tf.constant_initializer(0))
        H = activation(tf.matmul(tf.concat([rnn_input, state], axis = 1), W) + b)
    return H

# add RNN cells to the computational graph
state = initial_state
rnn_outputs = []
for rnn_input in rnn_inputs:
    state = RNNCell(rnn_input, state, tf.tanh)
    rnn_outputs.append(state)
final_state = rnn_outputs[-1]

# set up the softmax output layer
with tf.variable_scope('softmax_output'):
    W = tf.get_variable('W', [state_size, num_classes])
    b = tf.get_variable('b', [num_classes], initializer = tf.constant_initializer(0.0))

tf.summary.histogram('softmax_output/weights', W)

logits = [tf.matmul(rnn_output, W) + b for rnn_output in rnn_outputs]
probabilties = [tf.nn.softmax(logit) for logit in logits]
predictions = [tf.argmax(logit, 1) for logit in logits]

# set up loss function
losses = [tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels = label, logits = logit) for 
         logit, label in zip(logits, Y_one_hot_list)]
total_loss = tf.reduce_mean(losses)

# set up the optimizer
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(total_loss)

tf.summary.scalar('loss', total_loss)
```

This version of the session evaluates the training loss, takes a train_step, and then evaluates the loss again.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter( './RNN_Tutorial/temp1', sess.graph)
    summary = tf.summary.merge_all()

    for index, epoch in enumerate(gen_epochs(num_epochs, num_steps)):
        training_state = np.zeros((batch_size, state_size))
        for step, (x, y) in enumerate(epoch):
            training_loss1 = sess.run(total_loss, feed_dict = {X: x, Y: y, initial_state: training_state})
            sess.run(train_step, feed_dict = {X: x, Y: y, initial_state: training_state})
            training_loss2 = sess.run(total_loss, feed_dict = {X: x, Y: y, initial_state: training_state})

            if step % 1 == 0:
                train_writer.add_summary(summary_str, global_step = step)
                print(step, training_loss1, training_loss2)
```

The output looks like the model is not really learning. Here is the (partial) output, which doesn't really change through all 1000 iterations. It just sticks around 0.65 - 0.7

```
0 0.6757775 0.66556937
1 0.6581067 0.6867344
2 0.70850086 0.66878074
3 0.67115635 0.68184483
4 0.67868954 0.6858209
5 0.6853568 0.66989964
6 0.672376 0.6554015
7 0.66563135 0.6655373
8 0.660332 0.6666234
9 0.6514224 0.6536864
10 0.65912485 0.6518013
```

And here is the session when I run total_loss, losses, and final_state with the train_step:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter( './RNN_Tutorial/temp1', sess.graph)
    summary = tf.summary.merge_all()

    for index, epoch in enumerate(gen_epochs(num_epochs, num_steps)):
        training_state = np.zeros((batch_size, state_size))
        for step, (x, y) in enumerate(epoch):
            training_loss1 = sess.run(total_loss, feed_dict = {X: x, Y: y, initial_state: training_state})
            tr_losses, training_loss_, training_state, _, summary_str = \
            sess.run([losses,
                      total_loss,
                      final_state,
                      train_step,
                      summary], feed_dict={X:x, Y:y, initial_state:training_state})
            training_loss2 = sess.run(total_loss, feed_dict = {X: x, Y: y, initial_state: training_state})

            if step % 1 == 0:
                train_writer.add_summary(summary_str, global_step = step)
                print(step, training_loss1, training_loss_, training_loss2)
```

In this output, however, the total_loss calculated before the train step and the total loss calculated with train step have a steady decline and then plateau around 0.53 while the loss calculated after the train step (training_loss2) still fluctuates around 0.65 - 0.7 in the same way the first session did. Below is another partial output:

```
900 0.50464576 0.50464576 0.6973026
901 0.51603603 0.51603603 0.7115394
902 0.5465342 0.5465342 0.74994177
903 0.50591564 0.50591564 0.69172275
904 0.54837495 0.54837495 0.7333309
905 0.51697487 0.51697487 0.674438
906 0.5259896 0.5259896 0.70118546
907 0.5242365 0.5242365 0.71549624
908 0.50699174 0.50699174 0.7007787
909 0.5292892 0.5292892 0.7045353
910 0.49432433 0.49432433 0.73515224
```

I would think that the training loss would be the same for both versions of the session block. Why does using sess.run(total_loss, ...) then sess.run(train_step, ...) alone (i.e. in the first version) result in different loss values than when using sess.run([losses, total_loss, final_state, train_step], ...)?

Comment: What's the question here? Can you clarify the issue you're having?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Running the session without fetching and updating training_state = final_state within the second for loop was the issue. Without that, the model doesn't learn the longer dependencies built into the generated data.